# Method to display all numbers between 2 whole provided android

Tags: java, android

android code to display all numbers between 2 input from edittext

first edittext has starting number(min) and other has end number(max)..

Conditions.. Each multiple of 3, you need to display "H" instead of the number,
.. each  multiple of 5, you must display "S" instead of the number.
and other numbers are display as it is...

please help
thank you in advance..

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking so please clarify the question. Also, please show us what you've tried.
If I'm guess correctly you want to iterate over all numbers in the range and do something similar to `if(number % 3 == 0) { System.out.println("H");}`, `else if(number % 5 == 0) { System.out.println("S");}` and `else { System.out.println(number);}`

Comment: user enter range which he wants... as per range display all number between that range... but if number is multiple of 3, display "H" instead of that number and "S" if number is multiple of 5.. other number display as it is.. by the way you guess right and provide good solution.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText startnumtext= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourstartedittextid);
EditText endnumtext= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourendedittextid);

int startnumber=Integer.parseInt(startnumtext.getText().toString());// can throw a NumberFormatException if you put anything but digits inside the edittext

int endnumber=Integer.parseInt(endnumtext.getText().toString());// can throw a NumberFormatException if you put anything but digits inside the edittext

for(int x=startnumber;x<=endnumber;x++){   
    if(x%3==0){
       Log.d("MyActivity","H");
    }else if(x%5==0){
       Log.d("MyActivity","S");
    }else{
       Log.d("MyActivity",String.valueOf(x));
    }

}
```

This will show up in your LogCat output. If you need it on screen, use a Toast or a SnackBar or whatever way you find convenient.

Comment: yup... thanks man.. I used two time if condition instead of else if.. that give me wrong output..  its working now.. my silly mistake..

Comment: Just remember to handle the numbers that are dividable by both 3 and 5 (if that is relevant in your case), as it is now you treat those numbers as dividable by 3.

Comment: @RexWagenius Touche my friend :)